# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;&'

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

I'm trying to setup git on the server and following [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server). I'm getting error with this command

```
mkdir .ssh &amp;&amp; chmod 700 .ssh`
```

The error said:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;&'
```

Any idea?

Comment: I've submitted a bug report: https://github.com/progit/progit2/issues/540

Comment: Update: It's a known bug in [Atlas](https://atlas.oreilly.com/), discussed [here](http://forum.atlas.oreilly.com/t/angle-brackets-inside-source-block-are-replaced-with-entities-html-only/254). There's supposed to be a fix coming "soon" (as of November 2015).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `&` character was HTML-escaped on that page to `&amp;`. You should enter this instead:

```
mkdir .ssh && chmod 700 .ssh
```

Comment: Well, thanks. You helped me. Need time to accept your answer.